# Discover specific Bluetooth Low Energy Service by UUID in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Does anyone know how to discover a BLE Service by UUID in Android? There is a [discoverServices() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#discoverServices()) in Android, but there seems to be no way to discover one individual Service instead of all of them. In Bluetooth, discovering all Services takes a 'long' time, whereas discovering individual Services based on UUID does not take as long. It takes even longer for Android because Android also discovers all the Characteristics and Descriptors as well.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** you can't - if you don't want to do some really ugly and potentially dangerous hack.

There is no easy way to do this. If you look at what `discoverServices()` does on Nougat, you'll see it calls [GattService:L1454](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/nougat-release/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/GattService.java#1454).

```
void discoverServices(int clientIf, String address) {
    enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(BLUETOOTH_PERM, "Need BLUETOOTH permission");
    Integer connId = mClientMap.connIdByAddress(clientIf, address);
    if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "discoverServices() - address=" + address + ", connId=" + connId);
    if (connId != null)
        gattClientSearchServiceNative(connId, true, 0, 0);
    else
        Log.e(TAG, "discoverServices() - No connection for " + address + "...");
}
```

The key here is [gattClientSearchServiceNative](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/nougat-release/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/GattService.java#2333):

```
gattClientSearchServiceNative(int conn_id, 
                              boolean search_all, 
                              long service_uuid_lsb, 
                              long service_uuid_msb)
```

If `search_all` is *true*, it will scan everything. If not, it will search only a service with the provided UUID and its characteristics and descriptors.

You could actually try and use reflection to call this directly passing a *false* search_all parameter and a valid UUID, but that's a really bad practice and will end up crashing when a new version comes out and the internal implementation of this class changes.

Comment: is the service_uuid_lsb and service_uuid_msb the lsb and msb for the entire 128 bit UUID? 

Any idea why Google wouldn't provide an API to do this? Or even just an API to discover the Services and not all the Characteristics and Descriptors?

Comment: Yes, they are the MSB and LSB of the 128bit UUID. As for why it wouldn't provide it: my guess would be that the 'slow' part of discovering the BLE services of a device is not getting the service data but connecting to the device and requesting the data. So it would actually be quicker to ask for everything instead of asking for service A, end scan, then for service B, end scan...

You could probably ask about this on AOSP's google group.

Comment: Thanks for the information. In my case there's just one Service (out of many) that I want to discover, and then one Characteristic (out of many) for the vast majority of my use cases. General BLE best practice is to connect and only discover what you need and then disconnect again. I'll definitely ask on AOSP as well, thank you!

Comment: BluetoothLeScanner is supposed to do this now:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner